# How To Combine Two Seaborn catplot s with shared x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

i have a dataset with

| Categories | Model_1 | Model_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.49 | 0.13 |
| B | 0.52 | 0.13 |
| C | 0.46 | 0.03 |

I want to plot one figure with same x axis=Categories and y1=Model_1 and y2=Model_2 and I want result something like this :

[image]

I use this lines of code but he gives me 2 plots in differents figures

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Dataset.csv')

sns.catplot(x="Categories", y="Model_1",data=df,kind="point",markers=["o"],linestyles=["-"])
sns.catplot(x="Categories", y="Models_2",data=df,kind="point",markers=["^"],linestyles=["--"],ax = axs[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often it helps to reshape your data into a long format for plotting.  You can do this with `pd.melt`.  You wouldn't get lightly shaded confidence intervals like your sample image unless you had multiple values per category/model.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Categories': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Model_1': [0.49, 0.52, 0.46],
    'Model_2': [0.13, 0.13, 0.03]})

df = df.melt(id_vars='Categories', var_name='Model')
print(df)
sns.catplot(data=df,
            x='Categories',
            y='value',
            hue='Model',
            kind='point',
            markers=['o','^'],
            linestyles=['-','--'])
```

Output

```
  Categories    Model  value
0          A  Model_1   0.49
1          B  Model_1   0.52
2          C  Model_1   0.46
3          A  Model_2   0.13
4          B  Model_2   0.13
5          C  Model_2   0.03
```

[image]